# module 'telebot' has no attribute 'Telebot'

Tags: python, telebot

Выходит ошибка при запуске бота:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tatev\PycharmProjects\pythonProject4\myfile.py", line 5, in <module>
    bot=telebot.Telebot('TOKEN')
AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'Telebot'. Did you mean: 'TeleBot'?
```

Comment: вам же текст ошибки дает подсказку. или вы не читаете тексты ошибок?

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь.Вот крутые.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> AttributeError: module 'telebot' has no attribute 'Telebot'. Did you mean: 'TeleBot'?

В ошибке написано, что модуль, который вы используете (`telebot`) — не имеет объекта `Telebot` и предлагает исправление. Всегда внимательно читайте ошибки, в них все написано.